# vuejs2 component div inside table in laravel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

hi im using vuejs2 and this is my html code

```
<table border='5'>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    @include('treats.search_and_select')
</table>
```

and in `treats.search_and_select` i did this code

```
<tr is='search' :datas='datas' :search_title='"{{trans("language.".$search_and_select)}}"' class='user_search_and_select'>

</tr>
@section('js')
<script>
Vue.component('search',{
    template:
    '<div>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="o_td_label"><label class="o_form_label oe_form_box_warning">{{search_title}}</label></td>'+
            "<td><input type='text' @keyup='search_for_new_data()' /></td>"+
        '</tr>'+
        '<div v-if="result_from_search">'+
            '<tr v-for="result in results">'+
                '<td @click="test()">{{result.id}}</td>'+
                '<td>{{result.title}}</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>',
    data:function(){
        return {
            result_from_search:false,
            results:null,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        search_for_new_data()
        {
            axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => 
            (
                this.result_from_search = true,
                this.results = response['data']
            )
            )
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
        test()
        {
            alert("ADSf");
        }
    },
    props:{
        'datas':{},
        'search_title':null,
    }
});
new Vue({
    el:'.user_search_and_select',
    data:{
        datas:[
            {name:'awad',id:1},
            {name:'ghassan',id:2}
        ],
        search_title:null,
    },
});
</script>
@endsection
```

till now everything working so good except one thing thats the table is not ordered as tr td 
and this the image will come 
[image]
and this is the inspect elements
[image]
how can i fix this to make the income tr from component nested like others tr in table 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

For vue instance you need to put it on separated `div`, not in the table itself. Put your table inside it Like this :

```
<div id="app">   <!-- #app important -->
    <table border='5'>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
        @include('treats.search_and_select')
    </table>
</div>
```

Your component :

```
var TrTable = Vue.component('search',{
   template: 
       '<tr>'+
            '<td class="o_td_label"><label class="o_form_label oe_form_box_warning">{{search_title}}</label></td>'+
            "<td><input type='text' @keyup='search_for_new_data()' /></td>"+
        '</tr>'+
....
```

Init Vue instance :

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',  // bind To div#app
    components: {
        'search' : TrTable    // put your 'search' components here //
    },
    data:{
        datas:[
            {name:'awad',id:1},
            {name:'ghassan',id:2}
        ],
        search_title:null,
    },
});
```

Take a look a sample  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-static-table-component-q1cpx).

For vue instance, yes you need at a `div`. But not for component ( see docs here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Base-Example.

**Previous Answer :**

Since you are using `<tr>` :

```
<tr is='search' :datas='datas' :search_title='"{{trans("language.".$search_and_select)}}"' class='user_search_and_select'>
```

Try to remove `<div>` from template like this :

```
template: 
       '<tr>'+
            '<td class="o_td_label"><label class="o_form_label oe_form_box_warning">{{search_title}}</label></td>'+
            "<td><input type='text' @keyup='search_for_new_data()' /></td>"+
        '</tr>'+
        '<div v-if="result_from_search">'+
            '<tr v-for="result in results">'+
                '<td @click="test()">{{result.id}}</td>'+
                '<td>{{result.title}}</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</div>',
```

Also be aware a new problem with `<div>` again if `result_from_search` is `true` :

```
'<div v-if="result_from_search">'+
   '<tr v-for="result in results">'+
       '<td @click="test()">{{result.id}}</td>'+
       '<td>{{result.title}}</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
 '</div>',
```

Comment: this will not work ive to put all data inside one root element this is the error code [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Comment: I see, then I think you should try make the table component. not the tr component. because tr is inside the table. not like other lik p,br, h1 or div.